# How to convert an images folder into CBZ (like comics or mangas for Ebook)

Tags: image, powershell, directory

I just want to know how to convert an images folder into a CBZ file READABLE for my Ebook (I checked the ebook and she can read this format).

Optimally, I would like to convert it without having to install everything. Just a script.

*For those who are fast, I already answered my question... Just sharing it.*

Comment: I never imagined I'd see the subject of mangas come up in a PowerShell support site! +1 from me (once you post the answer)  :)

Comment: @Daniel Here's the answer my friend. Please, tell me if it don't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GO SEE UPDATE PART**

Assuming your OS is Windows, we can do it with Batch or PowerShell.

For this one its process is quite easy, we just need to understand that a CBZ file **IS** a ZIP file with images in it. So we will just:

1. zip with 7zip because for some reasons the files converted with WinRAR didn't worked in my Ebook (wasn't even in the library) ;
2. Change the extension from .zip to .cbz.

I'm only going to show the PowerShell one because the .bat script had known issues.

---

## Architecture

[Architecture of the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvLlZ.png)

The architecture should be:

1. My first folder

   - first image
   - second image
2. My second folder

   - first image
   - second image

---

## PowerShell

Here's the code from my "#_ImagesFolderToCBZ.ps1"

```
Clear-Host

# INPUT - Script folder path
$i = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
# 7Zip path
$7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
# A list of the path of the zipped files
$listOfZippedFiles = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]
$listOfZippedNames = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]

# Ask the user if we delete the folders after their conversion
$isSdel = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to delete the folders after conversion [Y/N]: "

# Get the files inside the INPUT path and forEach children
Get-ChildItem "$i" | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the full path of the file
    $pathFolder = $_.FullName
    
    # If the path here is a folder
    if (Test-Path -Path "$pathFolder" -PathType Container) {
        # Set the alias
        Set-Alias 7z $7zipPath

        # If the user asked for deletion of folders
        if ("Y" -eq $isSdel.ToUpper()) {
            # Zip the content of the folder
            7z a "$pathFolder.zip" "$pathFolder\*" -sdel | FIND "ing archive"
        }
        else {
            # Zip the content of the folder
            7z a "$pathFolder.zip" "$pathFolder\*" | FIND "ing archive"
        }

        # Add the file name into the list
        $listOfZippedFiles.Add("$pathFolder.zip")
        $listOfZippedNames.Add("$_.zip")
    }

    # If the user asked for deletion of folders
    if ("Y" -eq $isSdel) {
        # Remove the now blank folders
        if( $_.psiscontainer -eq $true){
            if((gci $_.FullName) -eq $null){
                $_.FullName | Remove-Item -Force
            }
        }
    }
}

# For each zipped file
foreach ($file in $listOfZippedFiles) {
    # Change the extension to CBZ
    $dest = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension("$file",".cbz")
    Move-Item -Path "$file" -Destination $dest -Force
}

# Write for the user
Write-Host "`r`n`r`nConverted:"

# Displaying the converted files by their names
foreach ($file in $listOfZippedNames) {
    $newName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension("$file",".cbz")
    Write-Host "-- $newName"
}

# Blank line
Write-Host ""
# Pause to let us see the result
Pause
```

### Output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqj04.png)

As we can see, the folder is sucessfully created AND **without** loops like : I have ZIP files in the root folder of the script and they are also renamed into CBZ ones (I had this loop for my batch script).

I also added the choice to automatically delete the converted folders **OR** not.

Obviously, there's room for improvements (especially in how we delete the folders). I'll gladly take any advice.

---

## UPDATE

I updated my script and it's much better. Less instructions, a list (in the prompt) that update itself when each folder is *really* converted. So no more: 1) ZIP all folders 2) rename their extension.

So a code that's more logic and also useful to show a beautiful process in real time.

Here's the updated code :

```
Clear-Host

# ROOT - Script folder path
$root = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
# 7Zip path
$7zipPath = "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

# Test if 7zip is installed
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $7zipPath -PathType Leaf)) {
    throw "7 zip file '$7zipPath' not found"
}

# Ask the user if we delete the folders after their conversion
$isSdel = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to delete the folders after conversion [Y/N]: "

# Write for the user
Write-Host "`r`nConverted:"

# Get the files inside the INPUT path and forEach children
Get-ChildItem "$root" | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the full path of the file
    $pathFolder = $_.FullName
    
    # If the path here is a folder
    if (Test-Path -Path "$pathFolder" -PathType Container) {
        # If the user asked for deletion of folders
        if ("Y" -eq $isSdel.ToUpper()) {
            # Zip the content of the folder while deleting the files zipped
            & $7zipPath a "$pathFolder.zip" "$pathFolder\*" -sdel > $null

            # Remove the now blank folder
            if( $_.psiscontainer -eq $true){
                if((gci $_.FullName) -eq $null){
                    $_.FullName | Remove-Item -Force
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            # Zip the content of the folder
            & $7zipPath a "$pathFolder.zip" "$pathFolder\*" > $null
        }

        # Change the extension to CBZ
        $newName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension("$pathFolder.zip",".cbz")
        Move-Item -Path "$pathFolder.zip" -Destination $newName -Force

        # Tells the user this one is finished converting
        Write-Host "--" -ForegroundColor DarkGray -NoNewline
        Write-Host " $_.cbz"
    }
}

# Tells the user it's finished
Write-Host "`r`nFinished`r`n" -ForegroundColor Green

# Pause to let us see the result
Pause
```

## UPDATE 2

I made a GitHub project for this one. The URL is here:
https://github.com/PonyLucky/CBZ-Manga-Creator.